# How do I solve this solve this error: LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax Error?

Tags: mysql, database, dataframe, syntax-error

Im trying to import a csv data into my table in mysql by using:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "r'/Users/temp/random_file.csv'"
INTO TABLE random_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "/Users/temp/random_file.csv'"
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And I really don't know why. All help is appreciated!

Comment: How are you doing that? when I copy/paste your command in MySQL-client, I do get `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.random_table' doesn't exist` (Which seems OK, because I do not have a table named `random_table`)

Comment: @Luuk I really don't know... and when I'm searching online nobody have had the exact problem before..

Comment: I am asking "How are you doing that?", and you reply with " I really don't know..." ?.... This leaves me (a bit) confused.

Comment: @Luuk sorry. Maybe I don't understand your question. How am I getting the error or what do you mean specifically? I am obviously using the command with the correct pathfile and table, but I still get that error.

Comment: I do mean in which context do you type this command?, you should use [mysql client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html)

Comment: @Luuk I am doing that now, and now I get this error:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'r'/Users/guest/Desktop/random.csv' INTO TABLE random_table

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE "r'/Users/temp/random_file.csv'"
```

The file name must be given as a literal string. You seem use raw string which is in Python. Change it to

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/temp/random_file.csv'
```